# Excel VBA: Autofilter with Array with more then 1 word in one specific Cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic, autofilter

i iam quite new but i wanted to create with a excel vba a macro code where i can filter out every word that is included in cell value E11 from a dataset on worksheet "Sheet1". The words are seperated with , (f.e. Cell E11 contains: ABX,BXC,CCC, so i want that those words are filtered out of the dataset)

This is a dynamic approach since i want to be flexible in the column number that i select aswell as the words that should be filtered out of the dataset.

When i run the macro i got the error: Complile error: Type missmatch

Where is the problem, can anyone help me please?

```
Dim product1 As Range
Dim product2 As Range

Dim arr() As String
Dim myarr() As String


 With Worksheets("Macro")

 Set product1 = .Range("D11")
    arr = Split(product1, ",")
    
 Set product2 = .Range("E11")
    myarr = Split(product2, ",")

 
End With

 With Worksheets("Sheet1")

  With .Range("A1:CS30000")
 .AutoFilter Field:=arr, Criteria1:="<>*" & myarr, Operator:=xlOr

End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CS30000").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle kopiert").Range("A1")

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:CS30000").AutoFilter
 
End With
```

Comment: You can only use up to two values when using autofilter with wildcards.  Also looks like you're trying to assign an array to `Field`, which is not going to work.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter#:~:text=The%20integer%20offset%20of%20the%20field%20on%20which%20you%20want%20to%20base%20the%20filter

Comment: The error is occurring because you cannot concatenate a string ("<>*") with an array (*myarr*). Are you aware that this `"<>*" & myarr` (if it would work) would mean *"doesn't end with"*? Is that the functionality you need? There are several workarounds, the easiest being if you would have another column with unique values. Do you have such a column? A screenshot of your data would help. Please add any additional information to [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74687630/edit).